# Ejecutar función al hacer click en boton o div contenedor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un div que contiene una imagen junto con dos botones dentro. Cada boton ejecuta una funcion de Javascript, pero ademas el div que contiene los botones y la imagen tambien puede ejecutar una funcion (aclaro que de estos divs se generan muchos automáticamente.

Lo que me pasa es que si hago click en un boton, ejecuta su funcion pero ademas la del div contenedor. 
Como podría hacer para que cuando hago click en un boton vaya a esa única función y no la del div contenedor?.
Gracias.

Asi creo los divs:

```
function CrearHTMLProducto(i, producto) {
var codigo = producto.Codigo;
var descripcion = producto.Descripcion;
var marca = producto.MarcaDescripcion;
var stkC = producto.StockC;
var stkSuc = producto.StockSucursal;
var stkSucs = producto.StockSucursales;
var precio = "0";
if (producto.PrecioPromocional != 0) {
    precio = producto.PrecioPromocional;
}
else if (producto.PrecioOferta != 0) {
    precio = producto.PrecioOferta;
}
else if (producto.PrecioLista != 0) {
    precio = producto.PrecioLista;
}
var html = "";
html += "<div class='col-sm-3' style='min-height: 480px; max-height: 480px' onclick='ConsultarProducto(\"" + codigo +"\")'><div class='thumbnail' style='min-height: 450px'><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12'><div class='col-sm-10 pR0'>";
html += "<label id='codProducto" + codigo + "' class='mT5 mB5 novaBold fS16'>" + codigo + "</label>";
html += "</div><div class='col-sm-2 text-center pad0'>";
html += "<div id='iconoVentaEnVerde" + codigo + "' class='icoVentaVerde dNone'>";
html += "<span id='letraVentaEnVerde" + codigo + "' title='Producto con venta en verde' class='fS16 novaBold cWhite'></span></div></div></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12'>";
html += "<div class='col-sm-12'><span class='novaLight fS19 cPrecio'>Precio</span>";
html += "<span class='novaBold fS21 cPrecio' id='precioProducto" + codigo + "'> $" + precio + "</span>";
html += "</div></div></div><hr class='hr-tres' /><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12'><div class='col-sm-12 pR0 fS12'>";
html += "<div class='col-sm-12 form-group m0 pL0'><label class='novaLight mB0 fS14 cStock'>Stock sucursal: </label>";
html += "<span id='stkSuc" + codigo + "' class='novaBold fS14 cStock'> " + stkSuc + "</span>"; 
html += "</div><div class='col-sm-12 form-group m0 pL0'><label class='novaLight mB0 fS14 cStock'>Stock COL: </label>";
html += "<span id='stkC" + codigo + "' class='novaBold fS14 cStock'> " + stkC + "</span>"; 
html += "</div><div class='col-sm-12 form-group m0 pL0'><label class='novaLight mB0 fS14 cStock'>Stock Sucursales: </label>";
html += "<span id='stkSucles" + codigo + "' class='novaBold fS14 cStock'> " + stkSucs + "</span>";
html += "</div></div></div></div><hr class='hr-tres' /><div class='caption text-center' onclick='location.href='#''><div class='position-relative' style='min-height: 253px'>";
html += "<img id='imgProducto" + codigo + "' class='imgNotFound' src='img/img_nd.png' /><a onclick='AgregarAlCarrito(\"" + codigo + "\")' class='carritoImagen'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-shopping-cart'></i></a>";
html += "<a href='agendaseguimiento/AltaEvento.aspx?p=" + codigo + "&v=f2" + "' class='calendarioImagen'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-calendar'></i></a></div></div><hr class='hr-tres' /><div class='caption card-footer' style='min-height: 51px;'>";
html += "<div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12'>";
html += "<h5 id='descProducto" + codigo + "' class='m0 novaLight fS15 cStock'>" + descripcion + "<span id='marcaProducto" + codigo + "' class='novaBold'> " + marca + "</span></h5>";
html += "</div></div></div></div></div>";           
return html;
```

Y esta es una de la funciones que llama el boton de carrito:

```
function AgregarAlCarrito(codigo) {               
            AgregarProducto(codigo, <%= Session["Vendedor"].ToString() %>, 1, "<%= Session["Sucursal"].ToString().Substring(0, 2) %>", "<%= Session["Sucursal"].ToString().Substring(2, 2) %>", "", "", "");
        };
```

Algo asi es lo que crea:
[image: Modelo_del_div_creado]

Este es un codigo de ejemplo del HTML que se crea con la funcion CrearHTMLProducto:

```
<div id='contenedorHAS2123GNB' class='col-sm-3' style='min-height: 462px' >
                        <div class='thumbnail' style='min-height: 450px'>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class='col-sm-12'>
                                    <div class='col-sm-10 pR0'>
                                        <label id='codProducto' class='mT5 mB5 novaBold fS16'>HAS2123GNB</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-sm-2 text-center pad0'>
                                        <div id='iconoVentaEnVerde' class='icoVentaVerde dNone'>
                                            <span class='fS16 novaBold cWhite'>P</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class='col-sm-12'>
                                    <div class='col-sm-12'>
                                        <span class='novaLight fS19 cPrecio'>Precio</span>
                                        <span class='novaBold fS21 cPrecio' id='precioProducto'>$32.045</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr class='hr-tres' />
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class='col-sm-12'>
                                    <div class='col-sm-12 pR0 fS12'>
                                        <div class='col-sm-12 form-group m0 pL0'>
                                            <label class='novaLight mB0 fS14 cStock'>Stock sucursal: </label>
                                            <span id='stkSuc' class='novaBold fS14 cStock'>12</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col-sm-12 form-group m0 pL0'>
                                            <label class='novaLight mB0 fS14 cStock'>Stock C: </label>
                                            <span id='stkC' class='novaBold fS14 cStock'>567</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col-sm-12 form-group m0 pL0'>
                                            <label class='novaLight mB0 fS14 cStock'>Stock Sucursales: </label>
                                            <span id='stkSucles' class='novaBold fS14 cStock'>34</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr class='hr-tres' />
                            <div class='caption text-center' onclick='location.href='#''>
                                <div class='position-relative' style='min-height: 253px'>
                                    <img id='imgProducto' class='imgNotFound' src='img/img_nd.png' />
                                    <button class="carritoImagen"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                                    <button class='calendarioImagen'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-calendar'></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr class='hr-tres' />
                            <div class='caption card-footer'>
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-sm-12'>
                                        <h5 id='descProducto' class='m0 novaLight fS15 cStock'>Descripcion producto<span id='marcaProducto' class='novaBold'> MARCA</span></h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Este esqueleto del HTML se repetiría tantas veces como productos se obtenga. Lo que quiero, es que al hacer click en el div con id 'contenedorHAS2123GNB' vaya a la función ConsultarProducto(codigo) enviando el valor del código del producto que tiene este contenedor en especial (HAS2123GNB en este caso). Si se hace click en el carrito que ejecute la función que le corresponde (AgregarAlCarrito(codigo) tambien con el código de este contenedor en especial) y lo mismo para el calendario.

Mi problema esta en que si hago click en el carrito o el calendario tambien se ejecuta ConsultarProducto cuando esto se debería ejecutar si se hace click sobre el div contenedor y no sobre los botones.

Comment: podrías añadir algo de código para ver qué estás intentando?

Comment: Si, pero es una funcion de javascript que crea el html y poco mas. No tiene mucho sentido pero ahi la agrego

Comment: Has intentado con jQuery?

Comment: No, lo unico que hice por el momento fue hacer los botones llamen a las funciones que tienen que ejecutar. Si se te ocurre algo con jQuery lo acepto tambien

Comment: Hola prueba estas ideas 1. desconecta los eventos click de los botones con el método unBind() o si prefieres con off() 2. Conéctalos usando on('click', function(event){ ... }); en function usas event.stopPropagation() y luego invocas el método específico del botón. Eso asegura que el evento no se propague al div.

Comment: @quevedo Hola, podrías explicarlo con un ejemplo en una respuesta? Porque entiendo un poco la idea pero quiero ver como se debería hacer bien

Comment: Hola. Si te sirve que lo haga usando jQuery podría ofrecerte un ejemplo dentro de un par de horas.

Comment: Si por supuesto @quevedo. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes organizar los divs y los demás elementos agrupándolos por clases según tus necesidades, luego, puedes agregar listeners por grupos o individuales según necesites.

Para el caso concreto de los divs, si quieres evitar que los listeners escuchen los clicks de los hijos, basta con agregar esto al inicio de la función:

```
if (e.target !== this)
  return;
```

Al poner eso, si el click no ha ocurrido sobre el `div` en sí, sino sobre alguno de sus hijos (imagen, botón u otro) retornará sin ejecutar nada de lo que haya más abajo.

Aquí te dejo varios ejemplos que luego puedes adaptar según lo que necesites. Todo lo demás es cuestión de organizar por clases que además te servirán para aplicar las reglas CSS adecuadas, como muestra también el ejemplo.

Como recomendación, te aconsejo que evites las funciones *in line*, como esta: `onclick='ConsultarProducto(\"" + codigo +"\")` así como los estilos *in line*, como esto:  `style='min-height: 51px;'`. Es una mala práctica. Actualmente se recomienda separar el código Javascript y CSS del código HTML por razones de mantenimiento. Si por ejemplo usas la función `ConsultarProducto()` en 10,000 archivos y hay que cambiar esa función añadiéndole más parámatros o lo que sea, tendrás que buscar esos 10,000 archivos, explorar el HTML y cambiar esa función allí. Si la tienes en un archivo JS separado del HTML sólo la cambiarás en ese archivo y listo. Por eso es mejor escuchar los eventos desde JS, no añadirlos *in line*. Lo mismo ocurre con el código CSS.

Dicho esto, veamos el ejemplo de código con los listeners de los divs funcionando por grupos.

```js
/*Este listener sirve para tareas comúnes a todos los divs*/
$(".allDivs").on('click', function(e) {
  /*Si no es el div en sí, retorna*/
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;

  /*Si es el div, entonces entra aquí*/
  console.log("Todos los divs");
});

/*
  Selector múltiple de clases para tareas por grupos
  Por ejemplo se escuchan dos clases de divs, 
  y se excluye el tercero
 */
$(".divOne, .divTwo").on('click', function(e) {
  /*Si no es el div en sí, retorna*/
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;

  /*Si es el div, entonces entra aquí*/
  console.log(`Hiciste click en ${this.id}`);
});

/*Escucha solamente al div 3*/
$(".divThree").on('click', function(e) {
  /*Si no es el div en sí, retorna*/
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;

  /*Si es el div, entonces entra aquí*/
  console.log(`Hiciste click en ${this.id}`);
});

/*Escucha todos los botones Borrar*/
$(".btnDelete").on('click', function(e) {
  console.log("Soy el botón Borrar de cualquier div");
});

/*Escucha todos los botones Agregar*/
$(".btnAdd").on('click', function(e) {
  console.log("Soy el botón Agregar de cualquier div");

});

/*Escucha los dos botones y recupera el código*/

$(".btnDelete, .btnAdd").on('click', function(e) {
  var codProducto=$(this).parent().find("label").text();
  console.log(codProducto);
});



$("label").on('click', function(e) {
  var codProducto = $(this).text();
  console.log(`Hiciste click en el label cuyo código es ${codProducto}`);

});
/*console.log($(".edit-section").find("label[for =delivery_name]").text());*/
```

```css
.allDivs {
  height: 140px;
}

.divOne {
  background: red;
}

.divTwo {
  background: green;
}

.divThree {
  background: orange;
}

.images {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divA" class="divOne allDivs">
  <img class="images" src="https://www.deiverbum.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/dv_logo_crismon_banner_400x100.png">
  <br />
  <label id='codProductoA' class='mT5 mB5 novaBold fS16'>HAS2123GNB</label>
  <button class="btnDelete">Borrar</button>
  <button class="btnAdd">Agregar</button>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="divB" class="divTwo allDivs">
  <img class="images" src="https://www.deiverbum.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/dv_logo_crismon_banner_400x100.png">
  <br />
  <label id='codProductoB' class='mT5 mB5 novaBold fS16'>IAS2123GNB</label>
  <button class="btnDelete">Borrar</button>
  <button class="btnAdd">Agregar</button>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="divC" class="divThree allDivs">
  <img class="images" src="https://www.deiverbum.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/dv_logo_crismon_banner_400x100.png">
  <button class="btnDelete">Borrar</button>
  <button class="btnAdd">Agregar</button>
  <br />
  <label id='codProductoC' class='mT5 mB5 novaBold fS16'>JAS2123GNB</label>

</div>
```

Comment: Primero gracias por la respuesta, por lo completa y las importantes sugerencias. Lo que me genera dudas, es que yo debo enviar el codigo del producto al que le estoy haciendo click (es "codigo" en el html). Y no sabria como enviarlo de la forma en que ejecutas las funciones.

Comment: @iMSn20 ¿en qué elemento o contenedor se encuentra dicho código?

Comment: En la función ´´CrearHTMLProducto(i, producto)´´ se envia un producto, dentro de ese producto esta el código. Este lo uso para identificar todos los contenedores de cada producto con un id diferente. Es necesario para que cuando llame a la función ConsultarProducto, pueda enviar el id del div contenedor al que le hice click y consultar otra pagina enviando como parámetro este código de producto.

Comment: @iMSn20 lo que te aconsejé de evitar funciones *in line* vale también para este caso. Desde Javascript tú puedes obtener ese valor por su id o por su posición dentro de un un contenedor. Imaginemos que el dato que te interesa está en un input u otro elemento de un `div`, desde el listener del div, o del elemento mismo, puedes obtener el valor usando `this`  por ejemplo. Si editas la pregunta poniendo un pequeño ejemplo en HTML te puedo mostrar cómo se hace.

Comment: Ahi agregue un ejemplo del HTML que se podría generar por medio de la función CrearHTMLProducto.

Comment: @iMSn20 Ok, pero para no tener que andar adivinando, dime por ejemplo qué valor quieres alcanzar: ***el valor tal en el div tal*** por ejemplo.

Comment: Ahí amplié un poco mas la pregunta. Yo lo que quiero es obtener siempre el código de producto para poder enviar tanto a **ConsultarProducto**, o para **AgregarAlCarrito** o para la **Agenda**. Ese código se encuentra por ejemplo en el parametro **producto** en la función CrearHTMLProducto (sería producto.Codigo).

Comment: @iMSn20 me refiero al HTML que has agregado. No veo ahí dónde estaría el dato relativo al código de producto que te interesa recuperar. Necesito verlo en el contexto para poder decirte cómo alcanzarlo.

Comment: Disculpa, no estaría entendiendo. El dato del codigo de producto se encuentra en ´´<label id='codProducto' class='mT5 mB5 novaBold fS16'>HAS2123GNB</label>´´. Ese HAS2123GNB se obtuvo por medio de una función de AJAX que trae todos los productos dependiendo de unos parametros y dentro del success del AJAX se hace un for por todo el largo de la lista de productos devueltos, y en cada iteración se llama a la funcion CrearHTMLProducto, donde producto sería el objeto Producto, que dentro tiene el Codigo.
No se si esto es lo que pedis, disculpa! Y de vuelta gracias por seguir ayudandome!

Comment: OK @iMSn20 primeramente te advierto que debes tener cuidado cuando generas elementos dinámicos. El estándar HTML prohíbe asignar el mismo `id` a más de un elemento del DOM. Significa que si generas elementos dentro de un  bucle o de otro modo debes asignar ids diferenciados usando un contador o algo así. Esto, aunque no se note en la vista, generaría un HTML erróneo. Dicho esto modificaré la respuesta, agregando un `label` en cada `div` y explicándote cómo podrías alcanzarlo.

Comment: @iMSn20 revisa ahora la nueva versión de la respuesta. He agregado en cada `div` una etiqueta `label` distinta. Luego he agregado un listener común a ambos botones donde se obtiene el código del `label` que haya en el padre. Esto serviría por ejemplo si quieres agregar ese id en algún sitio y también si quieres borrarlo. También he agregado un listener para todos los `label`, estén donde estén sólo para que veas que organizando bien tus elementos de acuerdo a lo que necesites hacer, tendrás formas de alcanzarlos por grupos o de forma individual. Si por ejemplo hubiera más de un `label` en ...

Comment: ... un `div`, podrías darles `name` distintos y alcanzarlos por el `name`. En ese caso el `name` se puede repetir varias veces, a diferencia del `id`. En fin, la clave es organizar bien los elementos y dotarles de clases cuando sea necesario, luego por esas clases los puedes agrupar, seleccionar, estilizar, etc. Si hay algo que no te queda claro me dices.